# What's the difference between float x[] vs. float[] x?

Tags: java, arrays

I was watching a video, and they showed that they were establishing a float array like this:

```
private final float x[];
```

I have always done this:

```
private final float[] x;
```

I tested both and neither produces an error.  Is there a difference or is this just preference?

Answer (score 4):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2):

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the
>   declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable,
>   or both.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];
> ```
>
> This declaration is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> byte rowvector[], colvector[], matrix[][];
> ```

There's no difference.

Answer (score 2):

No difference, the first syntax is just a C-like way to declare an array and the second was introduced with Java.

However, if you declare several variables on the same line there is a difference :

```
float[] a, b;
```

declares 2 arrays whereas

```
float a[], b;
```

declares an array and a float, but it is not a good practice to do that in my opinion.